# Ignore a quotation when calling terminal command using Python

Tags: python, ros

Hi I have a script to call a linux terminal command from python script and the backslash doesn't seem to ignore quotation marks.

```
import os

command='rostopic pub /test/fault msg/Fault \"name: \'data_error\' state: true\"'
os.system(command)
```

But I get the following error:

$ python testYaml.py
Usage: rostopic pub /topic type [args...]

rostopic: error: Argument error: while parsing a block mapping
in "", line 1, column 1:
name: 'data_error ...
^
expected , but found ''
in "", line 1, column 36:
name: 'data_error' state: true

The backslash doesn't ignore the quotation marks.

Comment: What do you mean by "backslash doesn't seem to ignore quotation marks"? When you use a backslash on a quotation mark, it uses it as a literal. So the quotation mark is used as a string. This is the output of `print(command)`: `rostopic pub /test/fault msg/Fault "name: 'data_error' state: true"`

Comment: If you normally invoke the command from a shell with the line `rostopic pub /test/fault msg/Fault "name: 'data_error' state: true"`, then the argument you are trying to pass is `name: 'data_error' state: true` (without double quotes).  The error message seems to be telling you that the `rostopic` command does not understand the leading double quote.   So it seems that python is, in fact, escaping the quotes as you want them to.  The problem is that you don't actually want the double quotes.

Comment: Why do you need to use the `os` module for this? This is already being run on a system with ROS deps, so I don't see why you wouldn't want to simply create a publisher?